# SCRIPT5022 Syntax Error in Microsoft Edge during postMessage

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, postmessage

```
window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), window.origin)
```

gives me Syntax error in Microsoft Edge, working ok in Chrome and elsewhere.

This is all that I see in the console:

[image: This is all that I see in the console]

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @epascarello I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you using Iframes in your code? If yes then try to post a working example of it. We will try to make a test with it. for testing purpose, try to post message using only Window.postMessage to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: @deepak-MSFT Yes, iframes. It looks like the problem was caused by my usage of `window.origin` - it's `undefined` in Edge, unlike Chrome & Firefox. I changed it to `window.location.origin` (as in standarts) and the error dissapeared.

Comment: @deepak-MSFT It would be nice if error message in Edge was more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.origin` is undefined in Edge, unlike Chrome & Firefox.

I changed it to `window.location.origin` (as in standarts) and the error dissapeared

Comment: THANK YOU so much, Mikhail! You might've saved me tons of hours of frustrated debugging here :))